# How to assign integers incrementally in C# (like last column) based on Type ID

Tags: c#

The data resides in SQL db, grouped on Type and Type ID. Whenever a new type id is encountered, an integer needs to be assigned like the last column.

| Type | Type ID | Features | Values | Assigned Int |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Coupe | 123 | Color | Red | 1 |
| Coupe | 123 | Engine | Petrol | 1 |
| Coupe | 123 | Brake | ABS | 1 |
| Coupe | 123 | Safety | Good | 1 |
| Coupe | 123 | Steer | Auto | 1 |
| Coupe | 123 | Seater | Four | 1 |
| Sedan | 589 | Color | Blue | 2 |
| Sedan | 589 | Engine | Diesel | 2 |
| Sedan | 589 | Brake | TDk | 2 |
| Sedan | 589 | Safety | Five Star | 2 |
| Sedan | 589 | Steer | Hydro | 2 |
| Sedan | 589 | Seater | Two | 2 |

Comment: Please add more description + code to your question

Comment: Please clarify what you are trying to achieve, add what you have tried, your issue/error with the code , and the code itself.

Comment: You mean: whenever a new TypeID is encounter, increment UniqueInt? Do the TypeIDs come sorted or at least grouped?

Comment: Where does this data live right now? In a remote database? In a c# variable like a datatable or List<T>? In some other place like a text file? ...

Comment: And when you say "incrementally like the last column", are you saying the last column is right, or are you saying it's wrong/what we need to help you fix? I ask because the column header says "unique" but many values are repeated, which is not the definition of "unique"

Comment: Just use *two* tables, one to store the type, another to store the properties.  A join to query them.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I'm still not 100% clear on whether the data stays in the db and c# makes a query that will assign it or whether c# will download it and assign it but..

If the data stays in the DB (or the db shall calculate the count) one way of doing this is to have the db join a subquery of distinct typeid together with an incrementing count. What starts off as a unique typeid-country pairing becomes repeated after joining

```
SELECT * 
FROM main
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT typeid, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY typeid) as ctr 
  FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT typeid FROM main
  ) x
) y on y.typeid = main.typeid
```

We get the unique type ids, we number them incrementally, and then we join this set back to the table

There are other ways such as running-summing a column that is mostly 0 but is 1 every time a sorted list of type of changes from row to row (effectively a `SUM(CASE WHEN LAG(typeid) = typeid THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) OVER(ORDER BY typeid)` but a bit more involved than that because of nesting the window functions)

---

If you're doing it in c# and you have downloaded the data into eg a List or datatable then the same logic as the above "if the row value changes since last time" works well:

```
var last = int.MinValue; var ctr = 0;
foreach(var x in myListOfThings) {
  if(x.TypeId != last) {
    ctr++;
    last = x.TypeId;
  }
  x.UniqueCtr = ctr;
}
```

The list needs to be ordered by typeid. If that's not already done, `foreach(var x in myListOfThings.OrderBy(t => t.TypeId))`

If you want to avoid a sort, you'll need to instead use a Dictionary to keep track of whether you saw a typeid before and what ctr you assigned it if you did see it/if you didn't see this typeid before assign a (ctr++). That looks more like:

```
var d = new Dictionary<int, int>(); var ctr = 1;
foreach(var x in myListOfThings) {
  if(!d.ContainsKey(x.TypeId)) 
    d[x.TypeId] = ctr++;

  x.UniqueCtr = d[x.TypeId];
}
```

You get the numbers assigned in whatever order the typeid is first encountered in the list

Answer (score 0):

It looks like all you need is a *ranking* function

```sql
SELECT *,
  [Assigned Int] = DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY t.[Type ID])
FROM YourTable;
```